# understanding tflite input output from tflite model

Tags: flutter, tensorflow, tflite

i'm following some online courses and i didn't understand why im always got
I/flutter (10799): Bad state: failed precondition and
E/SurfaceSyncer(10799): Failed to find sync for id=0

here is my code

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:tflite_flutter/tflite_flutter.dart';
import 'package:tflite_flutter_helper/tflite_flutter_helper.dart';

class Classifier {
  Classifier();

  classifyImage(var image) async {
    var inputImage = File(image.path);

    ImageProcessor imageProcessor = ImageProcessorBuilder()
        .add(ResizeOp(456,456, ResizeMethod.BILINEAR))
        .add(NormalizeOp(0,255))
        .build();

    TensorImage tensorImage = TensorImage.fromFile(inputImage);
    tensorImage = imageProcessor.process(tensorImage);

    TensorBuffer probabilityBuffer =
    TensorBuffer.createFixedSize(<int>[1, 120], TfLiteType.float32);

    try {
      Interpreter interpreter = await Interpreter.fromAsset("model2.tflite");
      interpreter.run(tensorImage.buffer, probabilityBuffer.buffer);
    } catch(e) {
      print(e);
    }

    List<String> labels = await FileUtil.loadLabels("assets/data2.txt");
    SequentialProcessor<TensorBuffer> probabilityProcessor =
    TensorProcessorBuilder().build();
    TensorLabel tensorLabel = TensorLabel.fromList(
        labels, probabilityProcessor.process(probabilityBuffer));

    Map labeledProb = tensorLabel.getMapWithFloatValue();
    double highestProb = 0;
    String dogBreed = "";

    labeledProb.forEach((breed, probability) {
      if (probability*100 > highestProb) {
        highestProb = probability*100;
        dogBreed = breed;
      }
    });
    var outputProb = highestProb.toStringAsFixed(1);
    print(dogBreed + "%" + outputProb);
    return [dogBreed, outputProb];
  }
}
```

[the model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XIzY7.png)

[the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6VnXj.png)